# Only using the intel graphics card modeset boot?

Tags: boot, graphics

So, I successfully got Ubuntu installed for the first time, but on each start up had to type and enter the noveau.modeset = 0. is there a way to disable whats causing me to need to do this or a detailed tutorial on writing some script to handle it for me? I'm pretty new to ubunt, but had to reinstall after downloading a nividia driver and being unable to access any terminal even with shift and e and other methods I looked up.

Comment: Why not add it to the bootloader configuration?

Comment: Sweet man! That appears to have worked. If you submit as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have no idea what that involves on Ubuntu, so it would not be appropriate for me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the boot option to the default used by your boot loader, by adding it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value in `/etc/default/grub`. Once you’ve done that, run `sudo update-grub` to update your configuration.